# PyInstaller 3.6: module importlib has no attribute 'machinery'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I have any issue trying to run my executable made by PyInstaller 3.6.

My code works fine in Idle, but doesn't run when made into an executable.

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'machinery'

This method that seems to throw the error only when using PyInstaller;

```
def getVariables(filename):
    '''Loads variables from variables.txt'''
    try:
        import importlib
        import types
        with open(filename) as f:
            loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader('data',filename)
            mod = types.ModuleType(loader.name)
            loader.exec_module(mod)
        return mod
    except:
        logger.exception('Exception occured:')
```

Things i've done:

- Re-installed PyInstaller; also tried multiple versions
- Re-installed importlib/importlib-metadata
- Tried different version of Python (3.6.5, 3.7.7)

I make the executable using the following command;

> pyinstaller --clean update.spec

update.spec:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
#import win32wnet,sys

import PyInstaller.config;
PyInstaller.config.CONF['distpath'] = "./apps/App/"
PyInstaller.config.CONF['workpath'] = "Z:\\Workspace\\David\\Applications\\src\\"

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['Z:\\Workspace\\David\\Applications\\src\\Update.py'],
             pathex=['Z:\\Workspace\\David\\Applications\\bin\\apps\\App'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=["win32process"],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='Update',
          icon='Z:\\Workspace\\David\\Applications\\src\\Icons\\Icon.ico',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=False,
               name='Update')
```

Version Info:

- Python - 3.6.5
- PyInstaller - 3.6
- importlib - 1.0.4
- importlib-metadata- 1.6.0

Comment: Might be a red herring but the examples in the docs show it being  used as `import importlib.machinery`

Comment: @match I'll see if that makes a difference.